# Bitfield concept in structure

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        struct value
        {
                int bit1:1;
                int bit2:4;
                int bit3:4;
        }bit;

        printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit));
}
```

I am using GCC, it is showing me the `sizeof(bit)` value as  4. Can you please explain how it works internally?

Comment: Fyi, the first of those, `bit1` is going to be pretty useless, since it is `int`, and thus one (and in this case the *only)*) bit is reserved for sign. Thus you have a positive (or negative) ... nothing. It will, however, occupy a bit regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig on two's complement architectures (that is, the usual ones), you can represent 0 and -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote `C11` standard, chapter `§6.7.2.1`, Structure and union specifiers, (*emphasis mine*)

> implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. **If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.** If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.....

In your case, as the (first variable type) `int` size is enough to pack all the bit-fielded variables into one `int`, it's doing so.

Thus, essentially your `sizeof(bit)` becomes equivalent to `sizeof(int)` which is likely to produce the value `4`, in 32 bit systems.

That said, `sizeof` produces a value of type `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier to print that value.

---

*[Added by Community Edit]*

- Case 1:

  If you use `char` as shown below, it'll show size as `1`, because 7 bits can fit in a `char`.

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {
      struct value
      {
              char bit1:1;
              char bit2:2;
              char bit3:4;
      }bit;

      printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit));
  }
  ```
- Case 2:

  In below case, the result will be '2' because it needs 2 `char`s to store `9` bits in total.

  ```
      char bit1:1;
      char bit2:4;
      char bit3:4;
  ```

Comment: thank you for your kind help. your reply is very useful.

Comment: @UtkarshPatel You're welcome . :-) BTW, you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler decided to lay out the bitfields in a single `int`, which is 32 bits on your platform. That means the structure as a whole requires 32 bits, even though the *usable part* of the structure is smaller.

Most machines aren't bit-addressable, so it really can't create an object that is 9 bits wide. It could have chosen 16 bits, and you can probably persuade it to do so with some `#pragma` or `attribute` magic. 32 bits is probably the most native size which gives best performance.